# What is wrong with this snippet of C code?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, copy

I am new to programming and was just playing around with some functions, I wanted to test the `memcpy()` function but my code simply just breaks without actually throwing an error, could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
int main()
{
    char *psz = "Hello world!";
    char dst[1024];

    memcpy(psz, dst, sizeof(psz));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error actually`

Comment: You cannot copy to statically allocated memory.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, it just says `Unhandled exception at 0x0F980E9A (msvcr110d.dll)`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry what do you mean by that? I am a little new to all this.

Comment: @JamesHiggins: Kindly do not edit the post in such a way that will invalidate the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two parameter values of `memcpy()` are backwards. The first parameter of `memcpy()` is the **destination**, the second parameter is the **source**. You are trying to copy a local (uninitialized) buffer into the memory of a string literal.  A string literal is stored in read-only memory, which is why you are getting a runtime error.

Also, your use a `sizeof()` is wrong, too.  `psz` is declared as a pointer. The size of a pointer is 4 bytes on a 32bit system, and 8 bytes on a 64bit system. If you reverse your buffer parameters, on a 32bit system you would copy `Hell`, and on a 64bit system you would copy `Hello wo`.

I suspect you intended to do the following instead:

```
memcpy(dst, psz, strlen(psz)+1);
```

Or maybe:

```
char psz[] = "Hello world!";
char dst[1024];

memcpy(dst, psz, sizeof(psz));
```

Comment: strlen(psz)+1 will be better so as to get the '\0' character

Answer (score 1):

The destination psz is pointing a constant string. 
So the error is being reported.
You probably want to do this 
memcpy(dst, psz, sizeof(psz));

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [memcpy documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/).

The correct usage is

```
memcpy (destination, source, num );
```

not

```
memcpy (source, destination, num );
```